# Verifying email address really exists

Tags: django, oauth, openid-connect, google-signin

I am using Google sign-in in my Django(V2.2.3) application which is to authenticate the user. So, I am requesting the response type as "authorization_code" from google and exchange it for id_token and exchanging id_token for user info.

Now, I have a case where a user's email id may be suspended after logged-in. So, I have to validate the email address at regular intervals. Since I am using Google sign-in, I am wondering whether I can use id_token to validate the email address. But the id_token expires in 1 hour. Is there any way to refresh the id_token silently without prompting the user to re-login?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the access token and using the access token you can query the Google userinfo endpoint to check detail about the user. Read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect)

After signin you have no use of the ID-token, only the access and the optional refresh token is available and usable after login.

Comment: Right, using access token I can query the user info. Since I am doing this validation once in 10 hours, every time I will get a new access token from refresh token and query the user info.

Comment: So, does this answer your question or what is missing?

Comment: It does help me. Every time I generate new access token from refresh token and based on the response and status code, I am handling it. Thanks